# How to use jTemplates' $P parameters within a {#if} condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jtemplates

Is it posible to use jTemplates' `$P.imagesPerRow` parameter inside the `{#if}` condition?

It raises "Uncaught 12" exception for me.

```
{#foreach $T as record}
    {#if $T.record$index % {$P.imagesPerRow} == 0}
        </tr>
        <tr>
    {#/if}
    <td class='image-preview-cell' style='width: {$P.cellWidth}; height: {$P.cellHeight}'>
    <img src='{$T.record.url}' title='{$T.record.title}' alt='{$T.record.title}'/>
</td> 
{#/for}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, and it is just a hunch, but try and change this line:

```
{#if $T.record$index % {$P.imagesPerRow} == 0}
```

to this:

```
{#if $T.record$index % $P.imagesPerRow == 0}
```